# Angular UI Router Dependent Component Resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the UI Router sample app there is an example where one resolve object is used in the next resolve.
https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-ng1/blob/master/app/mymessages/mymessages.states.js#L76

```
resolve: {
    // Fetch the current folder from the Folders service, using the folderId parameter
    folder: (Folders, $stateParams) => Folders.get($stateParams.folderId),

    // The resolved folder object (from the resolve above) is injected into this resolve
    // The list of message for the folder are fetched from the Messages service
    messages: (Messages, folder) => Messages.byFolder(folder)
  }
```

I have tried the below code in ES5 javascript but I get an error:

> `"Cannot read property 'propertyName' of undefined"`

```
resolve: {
 viewModel: ['viewModelService', function (viewModelService) {
        return viewModelService.get().then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }],
    anotherViewModel: this.viewModel.propertyName
}
```

Comment: what is `this.viewModel`? it's evaluated to `undefined`

Comment: `this.viewModel` is meant to be the `viewModel` object that has been resolved above `anotherViewModel`

Comment: see my answer then

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
resolve: {
    viewModel: ['viewModelService', function (viewModelService) {
            return viewModelService.get().then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    ],
    anotherViewModel: ['viewModel', function (viewModel) {
            viewModel.propertyName
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works well.

Comment: @WilJones, no problem. You can accept my answer if it helped.